# Access Denied from S3 Bucket [pendente]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

In Account A I created a s3 bucket with cloudformation, and a CodeBuild builds an artifact and uploads to this bucket. In Account B I try to create a stack with cloudformation, and use the artifact from Account A's bucket to deploy my Lambda function. But, I get an Access Denied error. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks...

```
"TestBucket": {
  "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
  "Properties": {
    "AccessControl": "BucketOwnerFullControl"
  }
},
"IAMPolicy": {
  "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
  "Properties": {
    "Bucket": {
      "Ref": "TestBucket"
    },
    "PolicyDocument": {
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root",
              "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
            ]
          },
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "arn:aws:s3:::",
                  {
                    "Ref": "TestBucket"
                  },
                  "/*"
                ]
              ]
            },
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "arn:aws:s3:::",
                  {
                    "Ref": "TestBucket"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the xxxxx in below statement is the account number of Account  B:

```
"AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root",
              "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
            ]
```

You are saying that this bucket grants the access to Account B on the basis of IAM permissions/policies held by them in Account B IAM service.

So essentially all the users/instance profile/policy that have explicit S3 access will be able to access this bucket of Account A. This means that perhaps the IAM policy that you are attaching to the lambda role in Account B doesn't have explicit S3 access.

I would suggest giving S3 access to your Lambda function and this should work.

Please be aware that in future if you want to write to S3 bucket of Account A from Account B, you would have to make sure that you put the bucket-owner-full-control [acl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html.) so that the objects are available across all the accounts.

**Example**:

**Using CLI**:
$ aws s3api put-object --acl bucket-owner-full-control --bucket my-test-bucket --key dir/my_object.txt --body /path/to/my_object.txt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"` granting access to the root role only, try granting access to all identities in the account by specifying just the account ID as the item within the `Principal/AWS` object: `"xxxxxxxxxxxx"`.

See [Using a Resource-based Policy to Delegate Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket in Another Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_policy-examples.html#example-delegate-xaccount-S3) for more details.